# sailsjs services: done not a function

Tags: sails.js

I have build a service function in sailsjs, which does basic authentication. 
Once local.authenticate finishes, on err I am able to refer to error().
If there are no error, the sails js is unable to access done() and crashes with indication "done is not a function".

```
module.exports = {
  auth: function (login, password, error, done) {

  var local_auth = function (login, password) {
      local.authenticate(login, password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return error({ err: err });
        } else {
          return done({ user: user });
        }

      });
    };
    local_auth(login, password);
  }
};
```

I call the service from controller:

```
authService.auth(user, pass, function (err, user) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friendly guys at sailsjs chat, showed me the error:

```
module.exports = {
  auth: function (login, password, done) {

  var local_auth = function (login, password) {
      local.authenticate(login, password, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return done(err, null);
        } else {
          return done(null, user);
        }

      });
    };
    local_auth(login, password);
  }
}
```